# Hashtable values not updating

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm tinkering with Java after a few years of largely ignoring the language and am having an issue that I cannot figure out. I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that I initialize with a series of 3 character strings. I want to find all instances of these strings in a larger string and store the counted occurrences within the Hashtable. I am attempting to do so using the following code:

```
private void countGenes(){
    int start = 0;
    int end = genome.length - 1;
    for(String key : genes.keySet())
    {
        int value = findGenes(key, start, end);
        genes.put(key, value);
    }
}

private int findGenes(String gene, int start, int end)
{
    if (start + gene.length() > end || !genome.toString().contains(gene))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return findGenes(gene, gene.indexOf(gene) + 1 , end) + 1;
    }
}
```

where `genes` is the Hashtable already initialized with a series of strings (the key) and set to zero count (the value). When I run this code, the debugger shows the recursive function `findGenes` appears to count correctly, but the values are not getting updated into `genes`.

I'm not familiar with Java's *for each* syntax, but I do know that other languages, like C#, do not react kindly to modifying an item being iterated over. However, I would expect an exception to be thrown; instead, this just doesn't update the item.  Perhaps there's some shadowing going on?

Comment: I think Java's logic is that you're fine because you're not modifying the keyset you are iterating over, you only change the values. Ps: `Hashtable` is dead, use `(Hash)Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your primary problem is on this line:

```
return findGenes(gene, gene.indexOf(gene) + 1 , end) + 1;
```

Instead of `gene.indexOf(gene)`, you should do `new String(genome).indexOf(gene)`.

Additionally, of what type is `genome`? I just noticed you are calling `.length` on it instead of `.length()`, so is it a `char[]`? In that case, an additional error may be in calling `genome.toString()`. The appropriate way to convert a `char[]` to a `String` is `new String(genome)` (although I'm not sure why you wouldn't just store `genome` as a `String`.

Comment: because of the number of character manipulations I'm doing in other portions, it made more sense to have it as a char array rather than a string.  There are fewer times I need to have it as a full string rather than as a char array.

Answer (score 0):

your method findGenes always returns 0 thats why you cant see anything else than 0 in Hashtable

Comment: No, in the recursive part he returns the sum of calling the method again and 1.